# Leaflet invalidate size - is not a function (undefined)

Tags: leaflet

I have a leaflet map that is nested within a div.  I have tabs.  When the tab that contains the leaflet map is the default tab, the map loads and works correctly. When it is not, it does not load correctly.  It does not load all tiles.

If I resize the page, it then loads.  I am trying map.invalidateSize but get an is not a function error.  Leaflet object properties at the time the invalidateSize is invoked are as follows:

```
_leaflet_dblclickdblclick4_2:r()
_leaflet_events: {…}
_leaflet_id: 3
_leaflet_pointerdowndblclick4_2:n()
_leaflet_pointerupdblclick4_2:o()
_leaflet_touchstarttouchstart15_16()
_leaflet_touchstarttouchstart23_24()
accessKey: ""
accessKeyLabel: ""
align: ""
assignedSlot: null
attributes: NamedNodeMap(3)
baseURI: "http://localhost/RG/#10/44.1206/-122.3067"
childElementCount: 3
childNodes: NodeList(4)
children: HTMLCollection(3)
classList: DOMTokenList(6)
className: "leaflet-container leaflet-touch leaflet-fade-anim leaflet-grab leaflet-touch-drag leaflet-touch-zoom"
clientHeight: 345
clientLeft: 0
clientTop: 0
clientWidth: 1036
contentEditable: "inherit"
contextMenu: null
dataset: DOMStringMap(0)
dir: ""
draggable: false
firstChild: #text
firstElementChild: div.leaflet-pane.leaflet-map-pane
hidden: false
id: "map"
```

I have the following code:

```
function openPage(pageName, elmnt, color) {

 // Hide all elements with class="tabcontent" by default */
 var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
 tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
 for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
     tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
 }

 // Remove the background color of all tablinks/buttons
 tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
 for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
     tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
 }

 // Show the specific tab content
document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";


if ([pageName] == "Flow") {
document.getElementById("FlowLog").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("lmap").style.visibility = "visible";
setTimeout(function(){ map.invalidateSize(true)}, 400);
}
}

 var map = L.map('lmap', {

//  preferCanvas: true,  //for leaflet image plugin
    measureControl:true,
    zoomControl:true, maxZoom:45, minZoom:1,
    center: ([44.120, -122.5951]),
    zoom: 11
   })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `map` variable seems to be a DOM element, not the leaflet instance.

You need to call the leaflet API on a map instance, which is linked to the dom element.

```
var map = L.map('my-map'); // my-map is the ID of your DOM map container
map.invalidateSize();      // should work then
```

Comment: Norwin. Your exactly correct. My code was accessing the Dom element and not the map instance itself. The Dom element and the map instance variable were both "map"  Thanks.  I have change the name of my Dom object. The issue now is that I call  map.invalidatesize when my tab is clicked, and I get a map is Undefined error.

Comment: Then your leaflet instance `map` is not accessible in the same function / scope as where you call `invalidateSize()`. To further help, we'll need more context (where `map` is defined, and everything in between).

Comment: I have edited and posted more code above.  Is this a hoisting issue??

Comment: This could well be, as variable *declarations* are hoisted in JS, but not their *initialization*. I recommend to always put variables at the top of the scope for this reason. Still it remains unclear when `openPage()` is called

Comment: openPage() is called when the user clicks on a tab...  after the page is loaded.

Comment: Spot on Norwin.  Put the var map = L.map("") statement up top and it now works.  Thanks so much for your help!